# Mapping multiple tables into a single Entity in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

In in a website's database I am working on, I have two tables for example: Country & CountryLocale. The two tables contain the following columns:

Country: Id, Longitude, Latitude
CountryLocale: Id, CountryId, CountryName, CultureId

What I want is:
- When I retrieve a Country, I want the Entity to contain: CountryId, CountryName, CultureId, Latitude & Longitude.
- When I create a new Country, to insert one record into Table Country and one to Table CountryLocale.
- When I create a new Country Locale, to create a record inside CountryLocale only

etc ...

Is this attainable?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use entity splitting to partially achieve that. `CountryLocale` would use the PK of `Country` as its PK. You can not insert to `CountryLocale` without a `Country`. Essentially its a single entity split into multiple tables.

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
        .Map(mc =>
        {
            mc.Properties(n => new
            {
                n.Id,
                n.Longitude,
                n.Latitude
            });
            mc.ToTable("Country");
        })
        .Map(mc =>
        {
            mc.Properties(n => new
            {
                n.CountryName,
                n.CultureId
            });
            mc.ToTable("CountryLocale");
        });
```

Comment: CountryId cannot be PK of CountryLocale, as I might have multiple CountryLocale records per Country. Where would the above code? More illustration please. Thanks

Comment: I am not using CodeFirst by the way. I have the Database already present and using Entity Framework.

Comment: @bhaidar Then obviously you can not map the properties in to a single entity. You would have to use a one-to-many mapping.

Answer (score 0):

use discriminator (Table per Hierarchy)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CountryBase>()
    .Map<Country>(c => c.Requires("Type").HasValue((int)CountryType.Country))
    .Map<CountryLocale>(c => c.Requires("Type").HasValue((int)CountryType.CountryLocale));
```

and you can define your sub-entities as you like

Comment: Can i have more illustration please? Thanks